# The Cluster service failed to bring clustered service or application 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)' completely online or offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server service restarted/stopped, which cause the production database down n find this errors in System log.

> ERROR5:The Cluster service failed to bring clustered service or
>   application 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)' completely online or offline.
>   One or more resources may be in a failed state. This may impact the
>   availability of the clustered service or application.
>
> ERROR4:Cluster resource 'SQL Network Name (tcsdb)' in clustered
>   service or application 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)' failed.
>
> ERROR3:Cluster network name resource 'SQL Network Name (tcsdb)' cannot
>   be brought online. The computer object associated with the resource
>   could not be updated in domain 'ABC.local' for the following reason:
>   Unable to get Computer Object using GUID.
>
> ERROR2:Cluster resource 'SQL Network Name (tcsdb)' in clustered
>   service or application 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)' failed.
>
> ERROR1:Cluster network name resource 'SQL Network Name (tcsdb)' cannot
>   be brought online. The computer object associated with the resource
>   could not be updated in domain 'ABC.local' for the following reason:
>   Unable to get Computer Object using GUID. how we can fix this issue

Comment: A quick google of your error message came up with this as the top hit: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2008654

Answer (score 2):

This means the cluster network name (tcsdb) can't be registered with Active Directory at the moment. It could be that your newly primary node can't see a domain controller, or can't see a writeable domain controller, may have a network interface down, may be having routing problems, etc.